# Better example than this?

Tags: general-topology

Even though local connectedness is preserved by homeomorphisms the image of a locally connected space under a continuous map may not be locally connected. Here is an example: $f: \mathbb N \to \{0\} \cup \{1/n\}_{\mathbb N_{> 0}} \subset \mathbb R$, $n \mapsto 1/n$ for $n \neq 0$ and $0 \mapsto 0$. The domain of $f$ has the discrete topology and is therefore locally connected but every nbhood of $0$ is disconnected. This is sort of artificial because in real life we don't deal with discrete spaces so I was wondering: does anyone know of any less artificial and maybe even simpler example?

Comment: Each example will still be a bit artificial, as the topology on the codomain must be strictly finer than the more natural topology which would be the quotient topology. This is because each quotient space of a locally connected space is still locally connected, so identifying points on the domain won't give you a non-locally connected space.

Answer (score 2):

The topologist's sine curve with the non-oscillating end going around and ending at a limit point of the oscillating part does something very similar to your example.

Comment: Though more "real life" it is not necessarily simpler. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just choose any non-locally connected space $Y$ and let $X$ be the same underlying set with the discrete topology. The identity map will do the work.

edit: blahrg, I did not see that you explicitly didn't want discrete spaces. Sorry.